# How do you 'mention' users in this hubot cron script for Slack, so they can see it as notification if their notification settings are on?

Tags: cron, hubot, slack-api

I have this hubot-cron script set up with heroku for Slack.  Works great with one exception.  If you '@' someone (mention) in Slack, users will get a notification depending on their notification settings. The way this is written, if put in a users name in the command text, Slack doesn't register it as a user, simply as text.

For example:

> hubot new job 2 * * * * * "@everyone testing"

When that is posted every two minutes, it may write @everyone, but Slack does not see it as actually '@everyone'.

What can be done with this code so where you can actually direct the job to @user?

```
# Description:
#   register cron jobs to schedule messages on the current channel
#
# Commands:
#   hubot new job "<crontab format>" <message> - Schedule a cron job to say something
#   hubot new job <crontab format> "<message>" - Ditto
#   hubot new job <crontab format> say <message> - Ditto
#   hubot list jobs - List current cron jobs
#   hubot remove job <id> - remove job
#   hubot remove job with message <message> - remove with message
#
# Author:
#   miyagawa

cronJob = require('cron').CronJob

JOBS = {}

createNewJob = (robot, pattern, user, message) ->
  id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) while !id? || JOBS[id]
  job = registerNewJob robot, id, pattern, user, message
  robot.brain.data.cronjob[id] = job.serialize()
  id

registerNewJobFromBrain = (robot, id, pattern, user, message, timezone) ->
  # for jobs saved in v0.2.0..v0.2.2
  user = user.user if "user" of user
  registerNewJob(robot, id, pattern, user, message, timezone)

  envelope = user: user, room: user.room
  robot.send envelope, "Job #{id} registered from brain"

storeJobToBrain = (robot, id, job) ->
  robot.brain.data.cronjob[id] = job.serialize()

  envelope = user: job.user, room: job.user.room
  robot.send envelope, "Job #{id} stored in brain asynchronously"

registerNewJob = (robot, id, pattern, user, message, timezone) ->
  job = new Job(id, pattern, user, message, timezone)
  job.start(robot)
  JOBS[id] = job

unregisterJob = (robot, id)->
  if JOBS[id]
    JOBS[id].stop()
    delete robot.brain.data.cronjob[id]
    delete JOBS[id]
    return yes
  no

handleNewJob = (robot, msg, pattern, message) ->
  try
    id = createNewJob robot, pattern, msg.message.user, message
    msg.send "Job #{id} created"
  catch error
    msg.send "Error caught parsing crontab pattern: #{error}. See http://crontab.org/ for the syntax"

updateJobTimezone = (robot, id, timezone) ->
  if JOBS[id]
    JOBS[id].stop()
    JOBS[id].timezone = timezone
    robot.brain.data.cronjob[id] = JOBS[id].serialize()
    JOBS[id].start(robot)
    return yes
  no

syncJobs = (robot) ->
  nonCachedJobs = difference(robot.brain.data.cronjob, JOBS)
  for own id, job of nonCachedJobs
    registerNewJobFromBrain robot, id, job...

  nonStoredJobs = difference(JOBS, robot.brain.data.cronjob)
  for own id, job of nonStoredJobs
    storeJobToBrain robot, id, job

difference = (obj1, obj2) ->
  diff = {}
  for id, job of obj1
    diff[id] = job if id !of obj2
  return diff

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.brain.data.cronjob or= {}
  robot.brain.on 'loaded', =>
    syncJobs robot

  robot.respond /(?:new|add) job "(.*?)" (.*)$/i, (msg) ->
    handleNewJob robot, msg, msg.match[1], msg.match[2]

  robot.respond /(?:new|add) job (.*) "(.*?)" *$/i, (msg) ->
    handleNewJob robot, msg, msg.match[1], msg.match[2]

  robot.respond /(?:new|add) job (.*?) say (.*?) *$/i, (msg) ->
    handleNewJob robot, msg, msg.match[1], msg.match[2]

  robot.respond /(?:list|ls) jobs?/i, (msg) ->
    text = ''
    for id, job of JOBS
      room = job.user.reply_to || job.user.room
      if room == msg.message.user.reply_to or room == msg.message.user.room
        text += "#{id}: #{job.pattern} @#{room} \"#{job.message}\"\n"
    msg.send text if text.length > 0

  robot.respond /(?:rm|remove|del|delete) job (\d+)/i, (msg) ->
    if (id = msg.match[1]) and unregisterJob(robot, id)
      msg.send "Job #{id} deleted"
    else
      msg.send "Job #{id} does not exist"

  robot.respond /(?:rm|remove|del|delete) job with message (.+)/i, (msg) ->
    message = msg.match[1]
    for id, job of JOBS
      room = job.user.reply_to || job.user.room
      if (room == msg.message.user.reply_to or room == msg.message.user.room) and job.message == message and unregisterJob(robot, id)
        msg.send "Job #{id} deleted"

  robot.respond /(?:tz|timezone) job (\d+) (.*)/i, (msg) ->
    if (id = msg.match[1]) and (timezone = msg.match[2]) and updateJobTimezone(robot, id, timezone)
      msg.send "Job #{id} updated to use #{timezone}"
    else
      msg.send "Job #{id} does not exist"

class Job
  constructor: (id, pattern, user, message, timezone) ->
    @id = id
    @pattern = pattern
    # cloning user because adapter may touch it later
    clonedUser = {}
    clonedUser[k] = v for k,v of user
    @user = clonedUser
    @message = message
    @timezone = timezone

  start: (robot) ->
    @cronjob = new cronJob(@pattern, =>
      @sendMessage robot
    , null, false, @timezone)
    @cronjob.start()

  stop: ->
    @cronjob.stop()

  serialize: ->
    [@pattern, @user, @message, @timezone]

  sendMessage: (robot) ->
    envelope = user: @user, room: @user.room
    robot.send envelope, @message
```

Comment: PLEASE start a bounty, also looking for an answer.

Answer (score 21):

To mention a specific user, send one of the following formats

`<@USER_ID>`

`<@USER_ID|user_name>`

To use one of the special @mention commands like @everyone:

> Currently defined commands are !channel, !group and !everyone (group is just a synonym for channel - both can be used in channels and groups). These indicate an @channel, @group or @everyone message, and should cause a notification to be displayed by the client.

So you'd want to send: `<!everyone>` to mention everyone.

So if I wanted to send a message mentioning stephen whose user id is U1234, I would send the following:

```
{
    "text": "Hey <@U1234|stephen> pay attention!"
}
```

or if I wanted to mention @everyone, I would do:

```
{
    "text": "Hey <!everyone> pay attention!"
}
```

Full docs on message formatting here: https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting

Comment: Just <@stephen> works too if stephen is a valid slack username.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `<!>` for special words.

> Some messages contain special words with extra behavior. For these we use the format `<!foo>`, where foo is a special command. - Slack

In your example, using `<!everyone>` to notify will work instead.